# How to enable javax.script in Websphere liberty profile on Bluemix?

Tags: javascript, java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I want to use JavaScript in one of my Java applications. So I ran this test:

```
javax.script.ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
javax.script.ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
System.out.println(engine);
javax.script.List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = manager.getEngineFactories();
System.out.println(factories.isEmpty());
```

Result:

```
null
true
```

So there's no JavaScript on default liberty profile. How do I activate that?

Comment: Does Jarek Gawor's answer here help? https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/194881/view.html

Comment: Yes it does. And when you repeat your comment as an answer I can properly accept it :-)

Comment: It also screws up the creation of the proper server.xml

Comment: You may need to build up a server xml similar to the default one in liberty on bluemix (https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html, scroll down to "Stand-alone Applications"). But the set of features available, and their versions, in the custom buildpack may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to build up a `server.xml` similar to the default one in liberty on Bluemix.  You can do this by uploading Liberty and your `server.xml` to Bluemix. Bluemix will pull out the `server.xml` and enable that feature.  Go [here](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/01/06/modify-liberty-server-xml-configurations-ibm-bluemix/) for more info.

Basically everything in `wlp/usr/servers/<yourservername>` needs to be uploaded to Bluemix with a `cf push` from `wlp/usr/servers/<yourservername>`.